# How do you know what fields are in a Laravel Model?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to unit test creating a `company` however I don't know what the fields/attributes of the model are.

So I look in `App\Company.php`, but there is no list of fields there.

Then I look at the migrations, but I have to go through each of them to find the fields available.

So as a last resort I open a DB explorer to find what fields are in the model.

Is there an easier way to know what fields exist in a model?

Comment: which is your database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way, without the need of loading any object from the db:

```
$fields = (new \App\Company())
->getConnection()
->getSchemaBuilder()
->getColumnListing((new \App\Company())->getTable());
```

Also you can:

```
$fields = Schema::getColumnListing((new \App\Company())->getTable()));
```

Comment: Yeah the first part is a bit long, the second is a lot simpler but not as simple as the answer above. What do you say?

Comment: @surfer190 I have nothing to say... It's up to you to accept the most useful answer. The main difference is that none of mine need to get an object from the database, and it works even with an empty table. If that's useful to you...

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use the `getAttributes()` method on an existing object.

This will give you all database columns of that object.

Comment: This only shows the attribute key and values if they have been set

Comment: @surfer190 no it also shows NULL/empty values, as long as it's an existing object loaded from the database.

Comment: Hmmm using `tinker` it doesn't. Just the `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` show.

Comment: Any `$hidden` columns?

Comment: Also you can't use a newly instantiated object, you need one which was loaded from the database.

Comment: Ahh that works, I was `saving` and then calling `getAttributes()` which doesn't work. Nice answer but it would make life easier if you could just call: `Company::getFields()`

Comment: @Amarnasan's answer is what you need. Just start `tinker`, then `Schema::getColumnListing('company');`

Comment: @amarnasan has a great answer I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I would search for the migration of the database table (in `database/migrations/`). If there isnt any migration I would go for the anwser @Luceos gave.